# Veracode CWE 89 help requested when attempting to load an excel file to a datatable in .net (web)

Tags: vb.net, webforms, veracode

Veracode SAST scanner is tagging excel file imports with a CWE 89 (Sql Injection):

> Attack Vector: system_data_dll.System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill
>
> Number of Modules Affected: 1
>
> Description: This database query contains a SQL injection flaw. The
>   call to system_data_dll.System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill()
>   constructs a dynamic SQL query using a variable derived from untrusted
>   input. An attacker could exploit this flaw to execute arbitrary SQL
>   queries against the database. Fill() was called on the adpt object,
>   which contains tainted data. The tainted data originated from earlier
>   calls to
>   system_data_dll.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar,
>   system_data_dll.System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable,
>   and system_web_dll.System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files.
>
> Remediation: Avoid dynamically constructing SQL queries. Instead, use
>   parameterized prepared statements to prevent the database from
>   interpreting the contents of bind variables as part of the query.
>   Always validate untrusted input to ensure that it conforms to the
>   expected format, using centralized data validation routines when
>   possible.

I am using the typical method of opening the excel file (uploaded by a user) through an oleDbConnection and loading a datatable with a specific worksheet.  It appears that Veracode is upset with the "Select * from [" & worksheetname & "]" - tagging it as SQL injection.  There is no way to use a parameter on the table name of an SQL statement.  I have attempted to use string substitution string.format("Select * FROM [{0}]", worksheetname). I have also attempted to scrub the worksheet name by removing obvious SQL actions (Select, update, insert, delete, execute).  A further constraint is that I do not know the name of the worksheet.  In some cases I am looking for partial words to be able to distinguish a particular type of upload - but I do not have a whitelist of all possible worksheetnames, although I have attempted to try a whitelist solution by passing the worksheet name in an sql query against a table (using a parameter) and returning a worksheet name and it triggers the same error (actually part of the error list above).

```
Public Shared Function ExcelFirstTableName(ByRef ExcelConn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection) As String
    '--http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318373
    Dim ExcelSheets As Data.DataTable
    Dim dr As Data.DataRow
    Dim FirstSheetName As String = Nothing

    ExcelSheets = ExcelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})

    For Each dr In ExcelSheets.Rows
        If (dr.Item("TABLE_TYPE") = "TABLE") Then
            FirstSheetName = dr.Item("TABLE_NAME")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next dr
    Return FirstSheetName
End Function

 Dim ExcelConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=""" & fName & """; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes = Text;""")

 WorksheetName = ExcelFirstTableName(ExcelConn)   
Dim adpt As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & WorksheetName & "]", ExcelConn)

adpt.Fill(dt)  <-- this is the line tagged.
```

...

The code functions fine - just trying to pass the Veracode scanner by removing SQL injection.